# Few questions about c#

Tags: c#

Could anyone answer on these questions?

1) There is a Microsoft's class: `SafeHandle.cs` I looked into the source and there are such methods:

```
[ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
public extern void DangerousAddRef(ref bool success);
```

or

```
[ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
public extern void DangerousRelease();
```

Where are the definitions of these method? Where Can I find them?

2) There is a method definitions which execute a method from the system library.

```
[ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity, DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint="WaitForSingleObject", SetLastError=true, ExactSpelling=true)]
private static extern int WaitForSingleObjectDontCallThis(SafeWaitHandle handle, int timeout);
```

Normally method: `WaitForSingleObject` accepts (HANDLE and DWORD).
How .net know how to obtain handle from the SafeWaitHandle class and how he does it?

Comment: @paolo I was trying to format the first code snippet to preformatted block, but cannot do nothing to make it. What is wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where does nativeGetUninitializedObject actually exist?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866179/where-does-nativegetuninitializedobject-actually-exist)

Comment: @John: I don't know. I've spent some time trying to do the same thing myself with no success... :)

Comment: @Hank Holterman How have you managed to format the code properly?

Comment: @john: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This method implemented as unmanaged function internally. You can download [Shared Source Common Language](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=4917) and take a look at that method implementation.

Here the code that I found in safechandle.cpp file:

```
FCIMPL2(void, SafeHandle::DangerousAddRef, SafeHandle* refThisUNSAFE, CLR_BOOL *pfSuccess)
{
    CONTRACTL
    {
        THROWS;
        MODE_COOPERATIVE;
        DISABLED(GC_TRIGGERS);
        SO_TOLERANT;
    }
    CONTRACTL_END;

    SAFEHANDLEREF sh(refThisUNSAFE);

    HELPER_METHOD_FRAME_BEGIN_1(sh);

    if (pfSuccess == NULL)
        COMPlusThrow(kNullReferenceException);

    sh->AddRef();
    *pfSuccess = TRUE;

    HELPER_METHOD_FRAME_END();
}
FCIMPLEND
```

But I'm not sure is it usefull or not.

---

And now about second question.

During marshalling from managed code to native code object marshallel converts any `SafeHandle` to `IntPtr` by calling `DangerousGetHandle` method.

During unmarshalling from native code to managed code there is opposed conversion: any `IntPtr` returns as `SafeHandle`.

When you're calling any unmanaged code that takes `DWORD` or `PVOID` we could pass `SafeHandle` or one of its descendants.

For example if we have a couple of external functions in our umanaged DLL:

```
PVOID CreateCustomHandle();
void ReleaseCustomHandle(PVOID handle);
```

We could call them in following way:

```
[DllImport("kernel32")]
public static extern MySafeHandle CreateCustomHandle();

[DLLImport("kernel32")]
public static extern void ReleaseCustomHandle(MySafeHandle handle);
```

Where `MySafeHandle` is subclass of `SafeHandle` class that knows how to deal with that particular resource.

Comment: Thanks You helped me. What about the second question?

Comment: During Safehandle to IntPtr conversion, how he knows which method should be invoked to actually obtain the underlying handle? (why it is: DangerousGetHandle)
And How does he knowh which method to use to create SafeHandle from IntPtr? 

or maybe it happens through the reflection. It is looking for a suitable method returning the expected variable type?

Comment: This marshaller actually not call DangerousGetHandle, at least I can't find direct call for that method. You can take a look at marshaler.h yourself (and to additional files as well, like cgenx86.cpp) but there are a lot of low level stuff that very hard to read and understand.

But any way, we can thing about it in following way: SafeHande is implicitly convertible to and from IntPtr by some internal CLR stuff. So anytime you have IntPtr in native code you should use SafeHandle or one of it descendants.

Comment: I was just curious about this staff because I have to rewrite some .net code to delphi code just for my needs.

Comment: Any way, this is very interesting topic!

Answer (score 0):

As the argument to the `MethodImplAttribute` might suggest, the methods you ask about in your first question are baked in to the CLR - they are the .NET equivalent of kernel calls.

As to your second question, type marshaling is handled by the CLR.  According to an [article from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), "for every .NET Framework type there is a default unmanaged type, which the common language runtime will use to marshal data across a managed to unmanaged function call."  In the link given by Sergey, there's a class defined (in "marshaler.h") called `SafeHandleMarshaller`; this appears to be the mechanism by which a `SafeWaitHandle` is converted to a native `HANDLE`.

Of course, the SSCL isn't the actual CLR codebase; nevertheless, it gives a good-enough idea of how P/Invoke marshalling works.