# Create instance without constructor via Reflection.Emit - possible?

Tags: performance, reflection, constructor, instance, reflection.emit

I've recently started learning Reflection.Emit, so I could replace all the Activator usages for better performance in my code. I'm currently thinking about some kind of serialization and deserialization library. Especially for deserialization I'd like to recreate the state of object exactly the same, as it was before serialization (I assume serialization is 100% correct). However, e.g. there can be class, that have multiple constructors, and every one does something sophisticated, because this object has complicated logic and has to be initialized some specific way. But when I have serialized everything about the object, the simplest thing I could do is somehow bypass any of the provided ctors - just make an empty object and fill it's all fields with data. Period.

Unfortunately, usage of `OpCodes.Newobj` in `ILGenerator.Emit` requires passing `ConstructorInfo` as parameter. For structs it would be easy, as they always have default parameterless ctor. However with classes things are different.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: It must be possible because `BinaryFormatter` creates objects without calling constructors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must be possible because BinaryFormatter creates objects without calling constructors.

You can use `FormatterServices.GetSafeUninitializedObject`. This is probably protected by highest security requirements.

Comment: Thanks, works just fine, though it lasts about 100us, which is pretty much. But now I can use Reflector to look inside and maybe I'll be able to get more performance :)

Comment: If you do find something, let me know.

Comment: Actually I did find few things:
1. Inside there is called method nativeGetUninitializedObject which is really a blackbox, as it is extern. I found something about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866179/where-does-nativegetuninitializedobject-actually-exist But it's not much, however:
2. I did more performance checks and it seems that GetSafeUninitializedObject is pretty undeterministic. Runned once lasted really about 100us, but when it was runned over 1000 times, it lasted just a few Ticks, and about 10000 and more - less than 2 Ticks (i.e. less than 200ns).

Comment: It was hard to believe that it might be that slow. It is a critical part of the serialization infrastructure. If it was slow it would show up on profiler results and be optimized. Serialization was a key technology 10 years ago.

Comment: You can try RuntimeTypeHandle.Allocate which is private. Create an accessor delegate using Delegate.CreateDelegate. I found it in reflectioninvocation.cpp.